# Get database from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have three tables like this:

Table 1:

```
id|name with row 1: [1|alex] and row2: [2|jane]
```

Table 2

```
nameid|classid with row 1: [1|2] and row2: [1|1] and row3: [2|2]
```

Table 3

```
classid|classname with row 1: [1|A] and row2: [2|B]
```

I want to get the ID on table 1, compare it with table 2 to get the class ID, then compare them with table 3 to get the class name. I have the ID from table 1, and I do this:

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE nameid='$id'") or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $classid = $row['classid'];
    //Get the class id to compare with table3
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE classid='$classid'") or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row['classname'];
       //Write down the class name
    }       
}   
?>
```

But in table 2, there are two rows (1 and 2) that have the same `nameid = 1`, but the code only prints one class name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are re-using `$row` and `$result` which is causing your issue.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE nameid='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $classid = $row['classid'];

    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE classid='$classid'")or die(mysql_error());
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
        echo $row2['classname'];

}

}
```

However you can get this in one query with a join.

```
select table3.classname from table2 left join table3 on table3.classid = table2.classid where table2.nameid='$id'
```

Also have to throw this in otherwise someone else will don't use mysql_* functions you should be using mysqli or pdo.